# How to disable autocomplete with v-form

Tags: forms, autocomplete, vuetify.js

I want to disable chrome autocomplete in my v-form. How do I do that? I don't see a autocomplete property on the v-form.

```
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/
```

While it is a property on a normal html form

```
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_autocomplete.asp
```

Answer (score 7):

By setting `autocomplete="username"` and `autocomplete="new-password"` on v-text-field you can actually turn off the autocomplete in chrome.

here is a code that worked for me:

```
       <v-form lazy-validation ref="login" v-model="validForm" @submit.prevent="submit()">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="user.email"
              label="Email"
              autocomplete="username"
            />
            <v-text-field
              v-model="user.password"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              autocomplete="new-password"
            />
            <v-btn type="submit" />
        </v-form>
```

Edit: autocomplete isn't set as a prop in vuetify docs but if you pass something to a component which isn't defined as prop in that component, it will accept it as an attribute and you can access it through `$attrs`.

here is the result of the above code in vue dev tools:

[image: autocomplete as inspected in vue dev tool]

and here is the rendered html:

[image: autocomplete as inspected in the html]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I don't see any autocomplete property on the vuetify docs https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#v-text-field-api

Comment: @MikeOttink I edited the answer and uploaded the result images of the code that worked for me, I hope it will help

Answer (score 6):

use autocomplete="off" in <v-text-field

```
<v-text-field
   autocomplete="off"
/>
```

Comment: Is this answer different from the existing https://stackoverflow.com/a/67123153/3124333

Comment: false is not an option on autocomplete, all must be off

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to get autofill disabled with the above methods, but changing the name to a random string/number worked.

```
name:"Math.random()"
```

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2792

Comment: Thank you... only this works for me... `<v-text-field :name="\`username_${Math.random()}\`"></v-text-field>`

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
autocomplete="false"
```

to your `<v-text-field>` or any input

Answer (score 2):

```
autocomplete="null"
```

This one prevents Chrome autofill feature

Comment: Thanks, this is the only working solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to get any of the previous proposals to work for me, what I finally did is change the text-flied for a text-area of a single line and thus it no longer autocompletes

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `type='search'` and `autocomplete="off"` props.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar problem. Nothing worked until I found this wonderful [Blog "How to prevent Chrome from auto-filling on Vue?"](https://dev.to/_ibrahimturan/how-to-prevent-chrome-form-auto-fill-on-vue-311c) by [İbrahim Turan](https://dev.to/_ibrahimturan)

The main catch is that we will change the type of **v-text-field** on runtime. From the below code you can see that the type of password field is assigned from the value **fieldTypes.password**. Based on focus and blur events we assign the type of the field. Also, the **name** attribute is important as we decide based on that in the **handleType()** function.

I'm also pasting the solution here:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-if="isloggedin" class="welcome">
      Welcome {{username}}
    </div>
    <div v-else id="form-wrapper">
      <label for="username">Username: </label>
      <input
        v-model="username" 
        class="form-input" 
        type="text" 
        name="username" 
        value=""
        autocomplete="off"
      />
      <label for="password">Password: </label>
      <input 
        v-model="password"
        class="form-input"
        :type="fieldTypes.password"
        name="password"
        value=""
        @focus="handleType"
        @blur="handleType"
        autocomplete="off"
      />
      <button class="block" type="button" @click="saveCredentials">
        Submit Form
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      isloggedin: false,
      fieldTypes: {
        password: 'text',
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveCredentials() {
      this.isloggedin = true;
    },
    handleType(event) {
      const { srcElement, type } = event;
      const { name, value } = srcElement;

      if(type === 'blur' && !value) {
        this.fieldTypes[name] = 'text'
      } else {
        this.fieldTypes[name] = 'password'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```